# is_home() and is_front_page() doesn't work in Wordpress Widget Logic plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show AdRotate content just in the main page of my blog by using this conditional tags: `is_home() && is_front_page()` also this other too `is_home() || is_front_page()` and didn't work. If I do this in `header.php`: `echo is_home();` I get 1 as result which make me think that's TRUE. Also if I try with echo `is_front_page()` I get the same result. What is wrong then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_home() && is_front_page()` will always be false. The two are mutually exclusive. The second version is the correct usage: `is_home() || is_front_page()`. Are you aware of the difference between `is_home()` and `is_front_page()`?

Take a look at the plugin FAQ page for more info on homepage usage: http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/faq/

Also further reading on the conditionals you're attempting to use:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page

Comment: Well I use the second version and didn't work since widget isn't displayed at home, that's the problem I'm having

Comment: I got problems using WidgetLogic like you. Usually problems starts on themplate rather than the plugin. Also take care about wp_reset_query() function to avoid issues. Try to change template then you will know what is causing it. Also you have a modified version called Widget Logic by Path, maybe can help you. Regards.